# Race Condition with Authlogic and Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, race-condition

I am upgrading an app to rails 4.1.1 and authlogic 3.4.2 and encountered a problem with a race condition in an integration test.

I have a page that issues two ajax requests upon loading. Both requests cause authlogic to try to update the logged in user record's last_request_at column. I do not always get the same exception, but something is always raised when the app tries to update the same user record back to back.

This was not an issue on rails 3 because they used Rack::Lock in the test environment.

Here is a snippet of the logs:

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1                                                                  [50/1923]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (1.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_request_at" = $1, "perishable_token" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('MedicalProfessional') AND "user
s"."id" = 2  [["last_request_at", "2014-05-18 00:19:46.564174"], ["perishable_token", "awlh6mBgHl2mdU2uboi"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-18 00:19:46.566315"]]
PG::Error: another command is already in progress
: UPDATE "users" SET "last_request_at" = $1, "perishable_token" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('MedicalProfessional') AND "users"."id" = 2
  SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_request_at" = $1, "perishable_token" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('MedicalProfessional') AND "user
s"."id" = 2  [["last_request_at", "2014-05-18 00:19:46.562637"], ["perishable_token", "SoXbKuCMs0Zu3vtxKGqn"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-18 00:19:46.564956"]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 132ms
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: another command is already in progress
: UPDATE "users" SET "last_request_at" = $1, "perishable_token" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('MedicalProfessional') AND "users"."id" = 2):
  app/helpers/auth_helper.rb:3:in `current_user_session'
  app/helpers/auth_helper.rb:7:in `current_user'
```

How should/can I resolve this issue?

Comment: IMO, ditch Authlogic if you're on Rails 4 and switch over to using `has_secure_password` if you don't need anything more complicated (like OAuth).

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to have to add something like a semaphore to your js if you really need to update the user from multiple directions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out someone else on my team had monkey patched ActiveRecord so that all threads use the same DB connection in order to speed up tests. He got the idea from this: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/

I was able to work around the issue by setting ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = nil at the start of the failing tests.